# Bind list on button click Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

What I want is when I click `id=addUnitCharge` button, `id = proName` and `id=proAge` should add in to `id=property_type_tbl` body. And when I click submit button all values should assign to(`id=code` and `id=school` as values and `id=property_type_tbl` values to `unitCharge` list)

This is my PlAccount class

```
public class PlAccount{

    private String code;
    private String school;
    private List<UnitCharge> unitCharge;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

UnitCharge class

```
public class UnitCharge{

    private String proName;
    private String proAge;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

My Controller class

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/product/add")
public String index(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("type", PlAccount.builder().build());
   return "/loan/product/add";
}

@PostMapping("/coopmis/waterTariff/product/add")
public String save(@Valid PlAccount plAccount, BindingResult result){
     plAccountService.savePlAccount(plAccount);
}
```

My html

```
<form method="post" action="/product/add" th:object="${type}">

    <input type="number" id="code" class="form-control" th:name="code">
    <input type="number" id="school" class="form-control" th:name="school">

    //On button click below Items should add to `property_type_tbl` table.
    <input type="number" id="proName" class="form-control" th:name="proName">
    <input type="number" id="proAge" class="form-control" th:name="proAge">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addUnitCharge" onclick="addRowPropertyType()"
          th:text="#{add}">Add
    </button>

   <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success " th:text="#{submit}">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>

<div class="form-group">
    <table class="table table-striped id="property_type_tbl">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th th:text="#{proName}"></th>
              <th th:text="#{proAge}"></th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Highly appreciate your kind support.

Comment: What have you tried already? What exactly is not working?

Comment: [link](https://vkuzel.com/add-or-remove-items-from-a-list-of-objects-in-a-model-attribute-using-spring-mvc-and-thymeleaf) Try following this tutorial, it worked for me with minor changes. In the th:each i removed the ",".